# Licensing question

Tags: support, asking-questions

Is there a stack exchange site that deals now with copyright issues, copyright infringement, and contribution ethics?

This is the closest I could find.

Answer (score 4):

We deal with all those **insofar as they specifically and principally relate to free software**.  For general copyright questions we often direct people to [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/), though I don't think we've ever actually gone over there to ask them if they're happy with it.

Comment: Lwa.SE does have almost 3,000 questions tagged [`[copyright]`](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright), but I also admit I don't have a strong understanding of what properties make a good or bad question under that tag.